# \makeatletter within a beamer frame: how?

Tags: beamer, catcodes

Within a beamer frame (not outside) `makeatletter` (or `\catcode`\@=11`) does not
work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\def\my@command{My at command}
\def\myatcommand{\my@command}
\makeatother
```

The following breaks with errors:

```
\begin{frame}
\makeatletter\my@command\makeatother
\end{frame}
```

The following works outside the frame

```
\makeatletter\my@command\makeatother
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
```

Only the following works inside the frame

```
\begin{frame}
\myatcommand
\end{frame}
```

Is there a way around this shortcoming (feature?) that does not involve a definition outside the beamer frame?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  You can't change category code inside a `frame` environment, because the environment's content is absorbed as a macro argument, so the category codes are fixed *before* `\makeatletter` is executed. Maybe some workaround is possible, but it's better not to use `@`-commands in the body of the document anyway. Can you make a more sensible example?

Comment: Thanks for amazingly quick reply. I think I can answer my own question now to some extent. The optional argument \begin{beamer}[fragile] fixes the errors. Perhaps that's the only way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @IanHutchinson Adding a little example code to your comment, you can provide an answer to your own question.

Comment: In a pinch, the following also works: `\csname my@command\endcsname`. It has the same effect as `\my@command`, but works without `\makeatother`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments