# How to "shallow" \renewenvironment of \itemize?

Tags: environments, itemize, patching

I want to patch exactly the outer level of \itemize, whereas the following MWE (expectedly) patches all of them:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\let\saveditemize=\itemize%
\let\savedenditemize=\enditemize%

\renewenvironment{itemize}
{\begin{minipage}{5cm}
    =foo=\saveditemize}
{\savedenditemize\end{minipage}}


\begin{itemize}
\item {External item one\\
  \begin{itemize}
    \item{Internal item one}
    \item{Internal item two}
  \end{itemize}
}
\item{External item two}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

..which is both evident and expected:

[image: =foo= appears twice]
..as =foo= appears twice.

My best attempt so far had the more-or-less direct approach, namely wrapping the contents with `\bgroup\let\itemize=..\let\savedenditemize=..} {\egroup` or, more precisely, replacing the `\renewenvironment` piece with:

```
\renewenvironment{itemize}
{\begin{minipage}{5cm}
    =foo=\saveditemize\bgroup\let\itemize=\saveditemize\let\enditemize=\savedenditemize}
{\egroup\savedenditemize\end{minipage}}
```

This, however, fails, since the `\begin\end` environment tracker apparently goes off rails:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{minipage} on input line 14 ended by \end{itemize}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.22     \end{itemize}

?
! Emergency stop.
 ...

l.22     \end{itemize}

No pages of output.
```

Having approached this problem from multiple angles for quite a while, I'm out of ideas..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in format? This seems like something better handled with the `enumitem` package.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see what you're trying to obtain.

Comment: The general context is this: 0. Beamer, 1. I don't control the TeX file, only the Beamer theme, 2. The (invariant) environment hierarchy is `\frame-\customenv-\itemize-\item-\itemize-\item`, 3. I need to be able to thoroughly rewrite the outer `\itemize`

Comment: Sorry, but that's really too vague. Also, if you're using `beamer` you should have made the example using `beamer`. The lists in `beamer` are not customizable using the same methods as in regular document classes, so this may make a big difference.

Comment: Alan, and you're perfectly right, indeed -- I have failed to port Ulrike's entirely valid answer into my `beamer` problem.  Shame on my head!  Would it be appropriate for me to ask another, similar question with the extended context?

Comment: ..and indeed, `beamer` is the culprit, as evident from another question: quoting @egreg : "Indeed, \begin{document} resets the category code of @ doing \makeatother, but only in beamer, not in the standard classes." -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141036/compilation-fail-with-pstool-begindocument-wrapped-in-makeatletter-makeato

Comment: ..and that was solved through replacing the `\makeatletter` context with escaping `\@listdepth` -> `\csname @listdepth\endcsname` -- as suggested in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161174/makeatletter-within-a-beamer-frame-how

Comment: @deepfire If you've managed to solve the `beamer` version of your question yourself, there's no need to ask a new question, but it might be useful to edit the question to show what you did to get the solution to work with `beamer`. If you haven't yet got it to work with `beamer` then another question (linking to this one) is certainly appropriate. P.S. If you precede names in comments with `@` then the person gets notified of the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nesting level is stored in \@listdepth, so you could check its value:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\let\saveditemize=\itemize%
\let\savedenditemize=\enditemize%
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{itemize}
{\ifnum \@listdepth=0\begin{minipage}{5cm}=foo=\fi\saveditemize}
{\savedenditemize\ifnum \@listdepth=0 \end{minipage}\fi}

\makeatother
\begin{itemize}
\item {External item one
  \begin{itemize}
    \item{Internal item one}
    \item{Internal item two}
  \end{itemize}
}
\item{External item two}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have failed to transplant the solution to my beamer problem, but this is a good step.